# Problem with Redux stored data in showing in table

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am learning `redux` I am trying to show my `initialstate` data in `table` and also the added data should be presented in table.

This is my `postReducer.js` file:

```
const initialState = [{name: 'jhon', age: '23', email: 'a@a'}, {name: 'doe', age: '24', email: 'b@a'}];

const postReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
      case 'ADD_POST':
        return state.concat([action.data]);
      default:
        return state;
    }
  }
  export default postReducer;
```

And this is my `table.js` file:

```
import React, {Fragment} from "react"


class Table extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            employees: this.props.state
        };

    }


    render() {
        return (
            <Fragment>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col">Name</th>
                        <th scope="col">Age</th>
                        <th scope="col">Email</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                {this.props.employees.map((item, index) => (
                    <tr key={index}>
                        <td>{item.name}</td>
                        <td>{item.age}</td>
                        <td>{item.email}</td>
                    </tr>
                ))}
                </tbody>
            </Fragment>
        );
    }
}

export default Table;
```

I am trying to show in table `initialState` data of `reducer` and i failed to do it.

Also i am trying to show add form data in same table

this is my `form.js` file

```
import React, { Fragment } from "react"

class Form extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {name: '', age: '', email: ''};
    }



    render() {
        return (
            <form>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <input name="name" type="text" />
                </div>

                <div className="form-group">
                    <input name="age" type="number"/>
                </div>

                <div className="form-group">
                    <input  name="email" type="text"/>
                </div>

                <button onClick={ (data) => this.props.dispatch({type: 'ADD_POST', data})} type="button">SAVE</button>

            </form>
        );
    }
}

export default Form;
```

And this is my `App.js` file:

```
import React from "react"
import Table from "./table"
import Form from "./form"

class App extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
        };
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>              
              <Form/>
            <hr/>
            <table>
                <Table />
            </table>
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
}
export default App;
```

And this is `index.js` file

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import App from "./components/App";

import { Provider } from 'react-redux'

import { createStore } from 'redux'
import rootReducer from '../src/redux/reducers/rootReducer'

const store = createStore(rootReducer)


ReactDOM.render((
  <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
  </Provider>
), document.getElementById('app'))
```

Can anyone please help me to display initial state data in table and also form data should be stored in reducer state and it should be displayed in table too?

Thanks

Comment: You aren’t correctly mapping your redux store data to props. Please review the documentation first regarding react-redux mapStateToProps(). https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapstate

Comment: I tried but i couldnt, can you please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To connect your component to the redux store, you would need to at minimum use [connect](https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect) and a [mapStateToProps](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapstate) function. This code assumes you are registering the reducer as "employees". Please note that you do not and should copy over redux mapped props to the component's state:

```
import React, {Fragment} from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

class Table extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Fragment>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col">Name</th>
                        <th scope="col">Age</th>
                        <th scope="col">Email</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                {this.props.employees.map((item, index) => (
                    <tr key={index}>
                        <td>{item.name}</td>
                        <td>{item.age}</td>
                        <td>{item.email}</td>
                    </tr>
                ))}
                </tbody>
            </Fragment>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({ employees: state.employees });

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Table);
```

Also, to be able to use `this.props.dispatch`, you would need to also `connect` the `Form` component:

```
import React, { Fragment } from "react"
import { connect } from "react-redux";

class Form extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {name: '', age: '', email: ''};
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <form>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <input name="name" type="text" />
                </div>

                <div className="form-group">
                    <input name="age" type="number"/>
                </div>

                <div className="form-group">
                    <input  name="email" type="text"/>
                </div>

                <button onClick={ (data) => this.props.dispatch({type: 'ADD_POST', data})} type="button">SAVE</button>

            </form>
        );
    }
}

export default connect(null)(Form);
```

You can simply/enhance dispatch by taking advantage [mapDispatchToProps()](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch) which would be passed in as an argument to `connect()`.

Please first review [Usage with react](https://redux.js.org/basics/usage-with-react) as well as the [redux tutorial](https://redux.js.org/basics/basic-tutorial) as it looks like you are missing some key concepts of Redux based on your code and question.

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Thanks, You made my day